# App freeze after a Titanium backup

Tags: titanium-backup

I experienced that, after a scheduled **Titanium Backup** backup, some apps (WhatsApp, Telegram, K-9 Mail, maybe others) doesn't appears to be running any more, i.e. I don't receive notifications from them. I have to open them to restore their functionality. Even a device reboot doesn't resolve the problem. This doesn't happen with other apps. Gmail, for example, continues to work.

This happen when the setting *app advanced control* from backup section is disabled, i.e. apps are killed instead of suspended and restored during a backup. May be that Android fail to restart the killed apps, or a behavior of the apps that prevent them to be restarted.

I have a Lenovo K50-t5 and tried with the ROW-1552D ROM, Android 5.1, customized by cuoco92, and with the Android 6 release.

Comment: I'm not sure how Android handles concurrent reads, but if the app was writing to its data while TB was backing it up it would probably get corrupted.  As such it would be extremely inadvisable to leave the apps running while doing a backup.  I can't comment on how the suspend/restore actually works, but a reboot should *definitely* resolve the problem you're seeing unless something is going very wrong.